# Compile Mono Project with embedded glib

Tags: mono

I have a .NET application that I want to run on an embedded processor runing Debian Linux (Power PC).

This limitted version of linux on the embedded processor does not have GLIB installed. So I want to compile mono using the embedded GLIB (EGLIBC).

> ```
> $ cd mono-2.8.2 
> $ ./configure CFLAGS=-O2 --prefix=/usr/local --with-glib=embedded --enable-nls=no
>
> Engine: 
>    GC:       sgen and bundled Boehm GC with typed GC and parallel mark 
>    GLIB:       embedded <----- Embedded Setting taken correctly 
>
> $ make 
> $ make install
> ```

Now, Mono is working fine on my Power PC computer (which has GLIB installed). I then FTP the mono executable (~8Megs) to my embedded device and I get the following error when I try to execute mono:

> ```
> dce> ./mono 
> ./mono: /lib/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.3.3' not found (required by ./mono)
> ./mono: /lib/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.6' not found (required by ./mono)
> ./mono: /lib/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.3.4' not found (required by ./mono)
> ./mono: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by ./mono)
> ```

I don't understand why mono is asking me about GLIBC library when I compiled using: "--with-glib=embedded". Also, after the "make install" I don't find any eglib library in the installed folder.

Answer (score 1):

Embedded glib is not the same thing as embedded glibc. They are completely different libraries.

Mono's "eglib" (embedded glib) is a reimplementation of a subset of one of the lowest-level GNOME libraries that eases cross platform programming in C and includes a lot of convenience functions and data types (like hash tables, etc).

You can read more about the glib API here: http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/

eglibc is an embedded version of glibc, the standard C library on Linux systems.